# Gomoku board in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, game

EDIT: The result looks like this: http://gomokuu.glitch.me/

This is my code for gomoku. I made it with JavaScript and HTML. I think the `checkWinner` function can be improved or made shorter. Also, should the functions be re-organized?

Here is the code:

Javascript:

```
var turn = 0;
var width = 15;
var height = 15;
var gameOver = false;
var board = Array(width * height);

function announceWinner(winner) {
  console.log("a");
  if (winner == 0) {
    window.alert("X wins");
  }
  if (winner == 1) {
    window.alert("O wins");
  }
  if (winner == 2) {
    window.alert("Board filled");
  }
}

function checkWinner() {
  var filled = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    if (board[i] == undefined) filled = false;
    if (board[i] !== undefined) {
      if (
        (board[i] == board[i + 1] &&
          board[i + 1] == board[i + 2] &&
          board[i + 2] == board[i + 3] &&
          board[i + 3] == board[i + 4]) ||
        (board[i] == board[i + width] &&
          board[i + width] == board[i + 2 * width] &&
          board[i + 2 * width] == board[i + 3 * width] &&
          board[i + 3 * width] == board[i + 4 * width]) ||
        (board[i] == board[i + 1 + width] &&
          board[i + 1 + width] == board[i + 2 + 2 * width] &&
          board[i + 2 + 2 * width] == board[i + 3 + 3 * width] &&
          board[i + 3 + 3 * width] == board[i + 4 + 4 * width]) ||
        (board[i] == board[i - 1 + width] &&
          board[i - 1 + width] == board[i - 2 + 2 * width] &&
          board[i - 2 + 2 * width] == board[i - 3 + 3 * width] &&
          board[i - 3 + 3 * width] == board[i - 4 + 4 * width])
      ) {
        gameOver = true;
        announceWinner(board[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  if (filled) {
    announceWinner(2);
  }
}

function tileClick(row, tile) {
  var clicked = document.getElementById("board").children[row].children[tile];
  if (clicked.innerHTML || gameOver) return;
  board[tile + row * width] = turn;
  if (turn) {
    clicked.innerHTML = "o";
    clicked.style.color = "red";
    turn = 0;
  } else {
    clicked.innerHTML = "x";
    clicked.style.color = "blue";
    turn = 1;
  }
  checkWinner();
}

//generate board and listen to click event
var domBoard = document.createElement("table");
domBoard.id = "board";
for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    var tile = document.createElement("td");
    tile.onclick = function() {
      tileClick(i, j);
    };
    row.appendChild(tile);
  }
  domBoard.appendChild(row);
}
document.body.appendChild(domBoard);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>gomoku</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to give you a full review, so I'll just add some comments about `checkWinner`:

- It will read better if you remove the mutation of global state from it.  Make it a pure function that returns `true` or `false`.
- You might consider using a 2D array as your data structure.  This isn't necessary, but it maps more naturally to the visual board, and will likely clean up some of your logic.

As for the duplication, you can remove a lot of it by introducing a helper function to capture the abstract logic that's being repeated in every block.  This will also clarify the high-level logic of checking for a winner:

```
function checkWinner() {
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    var rightWin = winAt(i, 1)
    var downWin = winAt(i, width)
    if (rightWin || downWin) return true
  }
  return false
}

function winAt(i, step) {
  if ( board[i] === undefined ) return false
  for ( var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    var nextIndex = i + (j * step)
    if ( board[i] !== board[nextIndex] ) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

#### EDIT: Answer to question

Green Ball, regarding the problem you mentioned with using a 2D array, there are ways around that: you can pad with extra rows of undefined, or you can abstract a `cell(i, j)` which hides the ugly bounds checking, and keeps it in one place.  Indeed, that last point is the key one, not whether you use a 1D or 2D array.

In your current implementation, the arithmetic logic around rows is forced out on the client: any code that wants to get an `i, j` pair must do the calculation itself.  Currently happens in `checkWinner` and `tileClick`: `board[tile + row * width]`.  It also happens implicitly in the double loop that constructs the html.

Regardless of the underlying structure that holds the `board`, you want your client code to be able to work with the concepts of "rows" and "columns" as first class citizens, since that's how we humans are thinking about this.  It will make the code more natural.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions :)
I'm not sure how a 2D array will work better. Here is a problem with 2D array. When you attemp to check if a tile in the current row is the same as the one in the next row (for vertical win) you'll do `board[i][j] == board[i+1][j]`. But if `board[i + 1]` is undefined (in case the current row you're checking is the last row) reading `[j]` will throw an error.

Comment: Off by one: 3 should be 4. Or even better: write `< 5` instead of `<= 4`, since the game is called 5 in a row.

Comment: Typo: it should be `!== board[next]` instead of `!== next`.

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks, fixed.  GreenBall, I replied to your question in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

In your `announceWinner()` function, you can shorten the multiple if statements to a one-liner with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like this:

```
function announceWinner(winner) {
  console.log("a");
  window.alert(winner == 0 ? "X wins" : winner == 1 ? "O wins" : winner == 2 ? "Board filled");
}
```

Or if you are sure that `winner` will always be `0`, `1` or `2`, then you can omit the last condition like this:

```
function announceWinner(winner) {
  console.log("a");
  window.alert(winner == 0 ? "X wins" : winner == 1 ? "O wins" : "Board filled");
}
```

---

In your `checkWinner()` function, you can push the multiple `board` array indexes to individual arrays and then use the [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to simplify the multiple conditions in your if statement like this:

```js
    function checkWinner() {
      var filled = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i] == undefined) filled = false;
        
        if (board[i] !== undefined) {
          let arr1 = [board[i+1], board[i+2], board[i+3], board[i+4]];
          let arr2 = [board[i+width], board[i+2*width], board[i+3*width], board[i+4*width]];
          let arr3 = [board[i+1+width], board[i+2+2*width], board[i+3+3*width], board[i+4+4*width]];
          let arr4 = [board[i-1+width], board[i-2+2*width], board[i-3+3*width], board[i-4+4*width]];
          
          if (
            (arr1.every(e=> e == board[i])) ||
            (arr2.every(e=> e == board[i])) ||
            (arr3.every(e=> e == board[i])) ||
            (arr4.every(e=> e == board[i]))
          ) {
            gameOver = true;
            announceWinner(board[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      if (filled) {
        announceWinner(2);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The player is called O, not 0.

Comment: Your variant of `checkWinner` creates lots of unnecessary objects. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to express this code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in an edge case. If the very last move, the one that fills the board, also creates a winning row, there will be two announcements. To fix this, you have to `return` after the winner announcement.

Except from this, the code is really simple to read and understand. Checking for a winner is quite slow, and if you should ever need faster code, this is where you can gain performance. But until then I suggest to leave the code as it is. It is short, to the point and elegant.

If you want to make the code less redundant, you can define a helper function inside `checkWinner`:

```
function checkWinner() {
    function fiveSame(start, step) {
        function same(i) {
            return board[start + i * step] === board[start];
        }
        return same(1) && same(2) && same(3) && same(4);
    }

    for (const i in board) {
        if (fiveSame(i, 1) || fiveSame(i, width - 1) || fiveSame(i, width) || fiveSame(i, width + 1)) {
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```